# Smartest way to check if an observation in data.frame(x) exists also in data.frame(y) and populate a new column according with the result

Tags: r, dataframe

Having two dataframes:

```
x <- data.frame(numbers=c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'), coincidence="NA")
```

and

```
y <- data.frame(numbers=c('1','3','10'))
```

How can I check if the observations in `y` (1, 3 and 10) also exist in `x` and fill accordingly the column `x["coincidence"]` (for example with YES|NO, TRUE|FALSE...).

I would do the same in Excel with a formula combining `IFERROR` and `VLOOKUP`, but I don't know how to do the same with R.

**Note:**
I am open to change data.frames to tables or use libraries. The dataframe with the numbers to check (`y`) will never have more than 10-20 observations, while the other one (`x`) will never have more than 1K observations. Therefore, I could also iterate with an `if`, if it´s necessary

Comment: Try `x$coincidence <- x$numbers %in% y$numbers`

Comment: see also the classic [merge / join Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) (especially when you want to add values from one dataframe to another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create the vector matching the desired output with a set difference search that outputs boolean `TRUE` and `FALSE` values where appropriate. The sign `%in%`, is a binary operator that compares the values on the left-hand side to the set of values on the right:

```
x$coincidence <- x$numbers %in% y$numbers
# numbers coincidence
# 1       1        TRUE
# 2       2       FALSE
# 3       3        TRUE
# 4       4       FALSE
# 5       5       FALSE
# 6       6       FALSE
# 7       7       FALSE
# 8       8       FALSE
# 9       9       FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Do numbers have to be factors, as you've set them up? (They're not numbers, but character.) If not, it's easy:

```
x <- data.frame(numbers=c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'), coincidence="NA", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y <- data.frame(numbers=c('1','3','10'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

x$coincidence[x$numbers %in% y$numbers] <- TRUE


> x
  numbers coincidence
1       1        TRUE
2       2          NA
3       3        TRUE
4       4          NA
5       5          NA
6       6          NA
7       7          NA
8       8          NA
9       9          NA
```

If they need to be factors, then you'll need to either set common levels or use as.character().